# No metadata for "entity" was found when seeding

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, faker

I'm building a seeding system using Faker over TypeORM throwing the following error on seeding:

```
  TypeORM Seeding v1.6.1
✔ ORM Config loaded
✔ Factories are imported
✔ Seeders are imported
✔ Database connected
⠹ Executing CreateUsers Seeder
❌  Could not save entity
EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "UsersEntity" was found.

✖ Could not run the seed CreateUsers!
Error: Could not save entity

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I'm using the CLI of the `typeorm-seeding` npm package in my `package.json`

```
"seed": "yarn migration:up && cross-env CLI=true ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js ---root src/core/config -n database-configuration.ts seed",
```

I have my `user.factory.ts` using the `users.entity.ts`

```js
define(UsersEntity, async (faker: typeof Faker) => {
  const user = new UsersEntity();
  user.firstName = faker.name.firstName();
  user.lastName = faker.name.lastName();
  user.email = faker.internet.email().toLowerCase();
  user.phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
  user.imageUrl = faker.image.people();
  user.password = await CryptoUtils.getHash('password');
  user.role = Role.User;
  return user;
});
```

And the `user.seeder.ts` to run the seeding

```js
export class CreateUsers implements Seeder {
  public async run(factory: Factory): Promise<any> {
    await factory(UsersEntity)().createMany(10);
  }
}
```

Finally, here is my database configuration used in the CLI to run the seeding

```js
return {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    entities:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/**/*.entity.ts']
        : ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: false,
    keepConnectionAlive: true,
    migrationsRun: true,
    logging: process.env.DATABASE_SHOW_SQL === 'true' || false,
    migrations:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/core/database/migrations/**/*.ts']
        : ['dist/core/database/migrations/**/*.js'],
    seeds: ['src/core/database/seed/seeder/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    factories: ['src/core/database/seed/factory/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/core/database/migrations',
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the `NODE_ENV` check on my **factories** and **seeds** files to avoid getting files in `dist` and `src`.

The problem was that I am working in `development` environment. The entities were found in the `dist` directory instead of **factories** and **seeds** who were found in the `src` instead of the `dist` folder.

The solution was to apply the `process.env.NODE_ENV` check on the **factories** and **seeds** too:

```js
seeds:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/core/database/seed/seeder/**/*.ts']
        : ['dist/core/database/seed/seeder/**/*.js'],
factories:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/core/database/seed/factory/**/*.ts']
        : ['dist/core/database/seed/factory/**/*.js'],
```